Javafx button not enable
I have a simple javafx program interface that contains a table for entering student data. There are 3 buttons for adding, updating, and deleting, but I made the buttons disable. There is an activate edit button. When pressed, a small interface appears for entering a password (qwerty1234). When the password is entered, the three buttons activate and the small window disappears, but the buttons do not activates even though there is no error or exception, so what is the reason?
This is the unlock method code:
@FXML
void unlock(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    if(txtactivate.getText().equals("qwerty1234")) {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        loader.load();

        FXMLDocumentController fxmlDocumentController = loader.getController();

        unlock_btn.getScene().getWindow().hide();

        fxmlDocumentController.btnAdd.setDisable(false);
        fxmlDocumentController.btnDelete.setDisable(false);
        fxmlDocumentController.btnUpdate.setDisable(false);
    } else {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("Error Message");
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText("Wrong Password!");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }
}

The buttons must enable but it does not


Please format your code at first. Does the window disappear when the unlock-button is clicked?

The small window(Enter password window)  disappear when the unlock-button is clicked but the (ADD-UPDATE-DELETE) buttons in main window are not enable

I would suggest, that it does not work, because this FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml")); ...load();... creates a new view and controller. But you want to enable the buttons of your current existing controller. You need to pass the reference of your controller to your dialog, and then disable the buttons from the referenced controller.

How can i do this please?....i mean what i  write in my code?

I can tell you only, if you post the code of the dialog too. Is the dialog using a separate fxml file and own controller?

Just in case: I published a library to maven central once, which can handle exactly this scenario easily: https://github.com/davidweber411/WedasoftFxGuiCommons. You can use it as dependency or just take a look at JfxDialogUtil.createAndShowFxmlDialog(...).

My friend I'm still beginning with the programming and I still learn Javafx ... I need a simple solution only .. I appreciate what you do for me, but do you have something easier to solve this problem please?

The simple solution, proposed by @DavidWeber, is "to pass the reference of your controller to your dialog." A more general solution, seen in the library cited, is to pass a reference to a functional parameter, callbackOnDialogClose, that handles the update. In either case, if you have trouble, please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your chosen approach and illustrates the problem you encounter.

Or even simpler (using the dependency): Pass a Runnable via an init(Runnable onUnlockButtonClickCallback) to the controller of your dialog and just call its run() after your "buttonAction" is done.
